# Creating an instance variable for 'this' in C#

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm going through some code, and I've come across something that appears rather strange to me. Here's a short example of what's being done.

```
namespace some.namespace
{
    public abstract class ClassName
    {

        private static ClassName _instance = null;

        private static ClassName Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance;
            }
            set
            {
                _instance = value;
            }
        }

        public ClassName ()
        {
            if(Instance != null)
            {
            return;
            }
            Instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there good reason for this that I'm missing? Throughout the code, there are references to `ClassName.Instance....`

Comment: It's the singleton pattern.

Comment: It's half a singleton. Usually the constructor is private/protected and the `Instance` is public.

Comment: That makes tons of sense now that I know what it's called. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's apparently an obscure and very poor implementation of singleton. Get rid of it and/or replace with a better implementation.

Comment: @TyCobb This is correct. This singleton implementation has some flaws.

Comment: As others stated, I would remove all that code and implemente a proper Singleton. This way you can't know from outside what's going on. You may think you are creating several objects but you are not, and that would lead to horrible bugs. When using a Singleton, that class is always accessed as `ClassName.GetInstance()`, and that way there is no doubt there is only one instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pattern called [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern
>   that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is
>   useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across
>   the system.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very naive implementation of the `Singleton` pattern. See [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for a deeper discussion of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already answered: this is a Singleton-Pattern. But it has some flaws.

1. It is not thread-safe.
2. It's constructor is public, this means it doesn't really serve the singleton principle: To ensure that there is only one instance of the class. You could simply create as many as you want.
3. The class is not sealed. This means you could inherit from this class and happily build instances from the sub-class.

See [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) about Singletons for a complete look at this topic.